Flights to and from continental Europe from Nuuk (Greenland) after Nov 28th, 2024
I am following the upgrade of the airport network in Greenland closely and I understand that finally on Nov 28th, 2024 the new upgraded airport in the capital city of Nuuk is going to be inaugurated. I also understand that the purpose of this upgraded airport is to offer direct flight connections to and from Nuuk to both North America and continental Europe.
Yet on popular airplane ticketing portals, I fail to find any suitable flight connections. Also on the website of Nuuk airport (actually, I am not sure they do have an official website) I find little information.
Does anyone know what's wrong? I thought that maybe the new connection as of Nov 28th are not yet in the flight connection databases which portals use, but at the time of writing, we're just ~ 1 month to go.
Did I misunderstand anything?

The schedules seem to be in place on Air Greenland's booking portal

Indeed. I cross-checked and it's only there, not on Opodo for example. Asking Opodo for the same dates you get the answer "There are no flights".

Air Greenland seem to have the schedules entered
For example, there is a Nuuk (GOH) to Copenhagen (CPH) a330-800neo direct flight on Monday, December 2nd
